# Поставить ударение в слове "счастливо"

Tags: орфоэпия

Как поставить ударение в слове "счастливо", в предложении "И счастливо идёт по планете завоёванная весна"?

Answer (score 1):

> Как поставить ударение в слове "счастливо"...

*<...> лет нашей славной Победе,*

*<...> лет как убита война,*

*И **счастлИво** идет по планете,*

*Завоёванная весна!*

Comment: Если стишок, можно и на вольность пойти :)  Гринписа дух зелён и светел:
Амурским тиграм жизнь дана.
Идёт счастлИво по планете
ЗавоевАнная весна.

Comment: Ну почему "счастлИво" вольность? Допускаемая орфоэпическими словарями форма. А в предложении, про которое спрашивала Вера,  именно такое ударение и требуется.

Answer (score 1):

Норма менялась. У Аванесова (1987 г) счАстливо, счастлИво - допускается, У Резниченко (2009)  указаны обе формы, но счАстливо - на первом месте.

Думается, здесь сказывается влияние краткой формы счАстлив (счастлИв - устар.).

Набоков:

И много лет прошло, и счастливо
я прожил без тебя, а все ж
порой я думаю опасливо:
жива ли ты и где живешь.

Рубцов:

Я запомнил, как диво,
Тот лесной хуторок,
Задремавший счастливо
Меж звериных дорог...
…

Answer (score 0):

СчастлИво. Строка написана анапестом, ритм в стихотворном тексте лучше сохранять.

--/--/--/-